# retrieving items from an array within a data object with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

i have an object of cars with make and model. Each make has different models. I am trying to built a search form that let's the user refine his search. When the user choose a make in a select the make field should be automatically be populate with the types corresponding to this make. This is how i do it:

```js
 $scope.myForm = [
        {
            Make: 'AUDI',
            Type: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A8', 'Q3', 'Q5', 'Q7']
        }, {
            Make: 'BMW',
            Type: ['316', '318', '320', '323', '325', '330']
        }, {
            Make: 'TOYOTA',
            Type: ['Avensis', 'Carina', 'Starlet', 'Landcruiser', 'Aygo', 'Hilux']
        }
    ]
```

```html
<h2>Search</h2>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="makeSelect">Make</label>
                <select ng-model="myForm.Make" class="form-control" ng-options="form.Make for form in myForm ">
                    <option value="" id="makeSelect">Select your make</option>
                </select>

                <label for="typeSelect">Type</label>
                <select ng-model="myForm.Type" class="form-control" ng-options="form.type for form in myForm.Type | filter:myForm.Make">
                    <option value="" id="typeSelect">Select your type</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </form>
```

It is not working, any idea?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to use meaningful names. You're confusing yourself by using bad names and storing the options and the selected option in the same place. So let's store the available cars in a variable named `cars`. And let's store the *selected* car in `selectedCar`:

```
$scope.cars = [
    {
        Make: 'AUDI',
        Type: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A8', 'Q3', 'Q5', 'Q7']
    }, {
        Make: 'BMW',
        Type: ['316', '318', '320', '323', '325', '330']
    }, {
        Make: 'TOYOTA',
        Type: ['Avensis', 'Carina', 'Starlet', 'Landcruiser', 'Aygo', 'Hilux']
    }
];
```

and

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" class="form-control" ng-options="car.Make for car in cars">
    <option value="" id="makeSelect">Select your make</option>
</select>
```

Now the second select should display all the types of the selected car. The selected car is stored in the `selectedCar`variable. The selected type will be stored in a variable called `selectedType`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedType" class="form-control" ng-options="type for type in selectedCar.Type">
     <option value="" id="typeSelect">Select your type</option>
</select>
```

The code would also be clearer if you use the plural form: `types` instead of `Type`.

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mm30HjQkgEOhJbZkyMic?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Could you explain me one thing please? The type array is in cars object, how did it get into selectedCar object?

Comment: That's what ng-model is all about: it allows storing the selected option (or the entered text in case of an input or textarea) in a scope variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```js
 $scope.myForm = [
        {
            Make: 'AUDI',
            Type: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A8', 'Q3', 'Q5', 'Q7']
        }, {
            Make: 'BMW',
            Type: ['316', '318', '320', '323', '325', '330']
        }, {
            Make: 'TOYOTA',
            Type: ['Avensis', 'Carina', 'Starlet', 'Landcruiser', 'Aygo', 'Hilux']
        }
    ]
```

```html
<h2>Search</h2>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="makeSelect">Make</label>
                <select ng-model="myForm.Make" class="form-control" ng-options="form.Make for form in myForm ">
                    <option value="" id="makeSelect">Select your make</option>
                </select>

                <label for="typeSelect">Type</label>
                <select ng-model="myForm.Type" class="form-control" ng-options="type in myform.filter(function(e) { e.Make == myForm.Make })[0].Type">
                    <option value="" id="typeSelect">Select your type</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </form>
```